# Decoding a Date in cim_bioselement that is clear in the WMI equivalent?

Tags: json, powershell, wmi, cim

In powershell, if i do `(gwmi win32_bios).releasedate | convertto-json`, I get `"20171221000000.000000+000"`, which makes sense - Dec. 21, 2017.

But if I take the equivalent element in the CimInstanceProperties list, e.g.,

```
$a = (Get-CimInstance cim_bioselement).CimInstanceProperties | `
where-object {$_.name -eq 'ReleaseDate'}
```

and then inspect `$a.value`, I get

```
Wednesday, December 20, 2017 6:00:00 PM
```

but doing `$a | ConvertTo-Json` yields

```
{
    "Name":  "ReleaseDate",
    "Value":  "\/Date(1513814400000)\/",
    "CimType":  13,
    "Flags":  "Property, ReadOnly, NotModified",
    "IsValueModified":  false
}
```

I'm guessing somehow those two dates are equivalent, but I don't have any immediate insight into what the format is for the CIM value after jsonification. I can grab a few more bios dates from different machines and start analyzing, but was curious if anyone knew what the format was "off the top of their head".

The reason I would like to understand the format is because it is what I get if I generically try to get all of the properties and jsonify, via

```
(Get-CimInstance cim_bioselement).CimInstanceProperties | convertto-json
```

Comment: Are you running this against a Windows machine? `(Get-CimInstance CIM_BiosElement).ReleaseDate` gives me a normal datetime-object directly (same as you would get after converting the wmi-format)

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in method for decoding CIMDATEs:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -Property ReleaseDate | 
    Select-Object @{n='ReleaseDate';e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.ReleaseDate)}}
```

Unless you're on PowerShell v1/v2 or run into problems, however, you should use `Get-CimInstance` over `Get-WmiObject` since it will do the conversions for you and is a bit cleaner:

```
PS> Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS -Property ReleaseDate | Select-Object ReleaseDate

ReleaseDate
-----------
8/5/2014 8:00:00 PM
```

---

To avoid Microsoft's stupid non-standard JSON date syntax, format the date yourself to a string in the correct ISO 8601 format:

```
PS> Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS -Property ReleaseDate |
    Select-Object @{n='ReleaseDate';e={$_.ReleaseDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')}}

ReleaseDate
-----------
2014-08-05T20:00:00.000Z

PS> Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS -Property ReleaseDate
    | Select-Object @{n = 'ReleaseDate'; e = {$_.ReleaseDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ')}}
    | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "ReleaseDate":  "2014-08-05T20:00:00.000Z"
}
```